# Getting error System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 when call apex from flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, limitexception

i have one flow that will create opportunity product in every opportunity child
i tried to make a apex class to seperate the process, and apex class will be called in the flow
but i still get error Too many SOQL queries: 101
this is my flow looks like
[image]

and this is my apex code;

```
public class Assign_Interested_Product_Opp {
    public class recordInfo {
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<Interested_Product_Channel__c> lstInterestedProd;

        @InvocableVariable
        public Id ChildOpptyId;
    }

    public class Results {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Records for Output' description='description' required=true)
        public String outputMember;
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Xd_AssignInterest')
    public static List<Results> execute(recordInfo[] lstRecordInfo) {
        Set<String> productIds = new Set<String>();
        List<Xendit_Opportunity_Product__c> lsXOP = new List<Xendit_Opportunity_Product__c>();
        Id childOpptyId;

        // Collect Product__c IDs from lstRecordInfo
        for (recordInfo info : lstRecordInfo) {
            if (info.lstInterestedProd != null) {
                for (Interested_Product_Channel__c myRecId : info.lstInterestedProd) {
                    if (myRecId.Product__c != null) {
                        Integer remainingQueries = Limits.getLimitQueries() - Limits.getQueries();
                        System.debug('Remaining SOQL Queries in Interested_Product_Channel__c: ' + remainingQueries);
                        childOpptyId = info.ChildOpptyId;
                        productIds.add(myRecId.Product__c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Query Rate_Card__c records for all productIds in a single query
        Map<String, Rate_Card__c> rateCardMap = new Map<String, Rate_Card__c>();
        for (Rate_Card__c rateCard : [SELECT Id, Rate_Per_TPV__c, Rate_Per_Event__c, CurrencyIsoCode, Rate_Per_Txn__c, Product__c FROM Rate_Card__c WHERE Product__c IN :productIds]) {
            Integer remainingQueries = Limits.getLimitQueries() - Limits.getQueries();
            System.debug('Remaining SOQL Queries in rateCard: ' + remainingQueries);
            rateCardMap.put(rateCard.Product__c, rateCard);
        }

        // Iterate through lstRecordInfo again to create Xendit_Opportunity_Product__c records
        for (recordInfo info : lstRecordInfo) {
            if (info.lstInterestedProd != null) {
                for (Interested_Product_Channel__c myRecId : info.lstInterestedProd) {
                    if (myRecId.Product__c != null) {
                        Rate_Card__c rateCard = rateCardMap.get(myRecId.Product__c);
                        if (rateCard != null) {
                            Id Rate_Card_ID;
                                Decimal var_Rate_per_TPV_Sell;
                                Decimal var_Rate_per_event;
                                String var_rate_card_currency;
                                Decimal var_Rate_per_Txn;
                                
                                Rate_Card_ID = rateCard.id;
                                var_Rate_per_TPV_Sell = rateCard.Rate_Per_TPV__c;
                                var_Rate_per_event = rateCard.Rate_Per_Event__c;
                                var_rate_card_currency = rateCard.CurrencyIsoCode;
                                var_Rate_per_Txn = rateCard.Rate_Per_Txn__c; 
                                // Check if required fields are not null
                                Xendit_Opportunity_Product__c OpptyProductSingleVar = new Xendit_Opportunity_Product__c();
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Rate_Card__c = rateCard.Id;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.TPV__c = myRecId.Channel_Potential_TPV_local__c;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Product__c = myRecId.Product__c;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Opportunity__c = ChildOpptyId ;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Rate_Per_TPV_Sell__c = var_Rate_per_TPV_Sell; 
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Rate_Per_Txn_Sell__c = var_Rate_per_Txn;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.CurrencyIsoCode = var_rate_card_currency;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Rate_Per_Event_Sell__c = var_Rate_per_event;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Rate_Per_Event_List__c = var_Rate_per_event;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Rate_Per_TPV_List__c = var_Rate_per_TPV_Sell;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Rate_Per_Txn_List__c = var_Rate_per_Txn;
                                
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.Basket_Size__c = myRecId.Product_Basket_Size__c;
                                OpptyProductSingleVar.From_Lead_Conversion__c = true;
                                
                                
                                lsXOP.add(OpptyProductSingleVar);
                        } else {
                            System.debug('Handle the case where no Rate_Card__c records were found for the Product__c');
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.debug('Handle the case where myRecId.Product__c is null');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.debug('lsXOP ID:' + lsXOP);
        insert lsXOP;
        Results response = new Results();
        response.outputMember = 'True';
        List<Results> responseWrapper = new List<Results>();
        responseWrapper.add(response);

        return responseWrapper;
    }
}
```

This is the error detail
[image]

Do you guys have any idea what should i do? i really need your help, thankyou